# Как убрать пробелы в номере телефона. a href="tel:"

Tags: html

http://clip2net.com/s/6tArId

Вот мне не нужны эти пробелы в телефоне. Позвонить нельзя.

```
<a href="tel:+84994095318" class="ph"><span class="turq">8 (499)</span> 409-53-18</a>
```

Вот такая ссылка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Звонит оно на +84994095318, и судя по всему - это Въетнам, и не факт что номер правильный.
Указывать нужно вместе с кодом страны. Например для росcии нужно писать так:

```
<a href="tel:+74994095318" class="ph"><span class="turq">8 (499)</span> 409-53-18</a>
```

Если всё же номер правильный, то попробуйте так сделать:

```
<a href="wtai://wp/mc;+84994095318" class="ph"><span class="turq">8 (499)</span> 409-53-18</a>
```

Comment: Номер правильный, wtai не звонит. 

Но если номер набирается то отлично, но у меня не получается позвонить.

Comment: @vkovalchuk88, говорят же вам, +7 надо в tel писать, а не +8. Номер у вас российский, я уверен (даже знаю чей). Сейчас проверил, c +7 работает на iOS.

Comment: @dzhioev, почему все номера тогда у меня начинаются с восьмерки, ну окей я разберусь мне главное что звонит.

Comment: можно конечно и с 8кой попробывать, но + тогда нужно убрать. НО работать будет только внутри россии